Azure Functions dynamicConcurrencyEnabled setting doesn't work
Our Azure Functions are using runtime version 4, I've upgraded Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage to 5.3.1 as required to be able to utilise dynamic concurrency.
When I add enable dynamic concurrency as per below in the host.json file... all functions seem to be throttled to death and basically timeout?
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true
  }

Seems like a great feature... except it doesn't work? What am I missing?
Here is the complete host.json if that helps
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "MyProject.Common.Azure": "Information"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:00.100"
    }
  }
}

Stack Settings


Can you share the code which you have tried with the dynamic concurrency configuration?

Hey @Pavan it's just basic http trigger / queue trigger functions.

Try setting "concurrency": {    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true  } in host.json

I have tried the same and it worked and able to run the function, refer image.

Add below configuration in host.json to enable dynamic concurrency in your function app, refer the article:
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "concurrency": {
        "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
        "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
    }
}

Set the functionTimeout in host.json:
"functionTimeout":"00:30:00"

I have created a Queue Trigger and Http Trigger in a function project.
host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00",
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "MyProject.Common.Azure": "Information"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:00.100"
    }
  }
}

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Deployed the functions to Azure function app with Consumption Plan.

The concurrency value of the function is stored in the storage account specified in the AzureWebjobsStorage app setting.
The values are stored in concurrencyStatus.json file under azure-webjobs-hosts=>concurrency=> functionApp_Name folder=> concurrencyStatus.json.

Able to run the function as expected:

